# 1st argument of JavaScript apply function

Tags: javascript, apply

I started to learn the `apply` function from this [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

In the following example, the function invocation with `apply` and that without `apply` have the same output.

```
console.log(Math.max(5, 6, 2, 3, 7)); // output:7
console.log(Math.max.apply(null, [5, 6, 2, 3, 7])); // output:7
```

However, when I adopted the same way on the following example, the outputs are different.

```
class Animal { 
  speak() {
    return this;
  }
}

let obj = new Animal();
let speak = obj.speak;
console.log(speak()); // output:undefined
console.log(speak.apply(null, [])); // output:null
```

It seems passing `null` as the 1st argument of `apply` may change the behavior of the function. Using `undefined` does not have this side effect. For example:

```
console.log(Math.max.apply(undefined, [5, 6, 2, 3, 7])); // output:7
console.log(speak.apply(undefined, [])); // output:undefined
```

So is it safer to use `undefined` than `null` in most cases? (suppose we only focus on cases where there is no `this` object for the function call)

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense. The first argument sets the value of `this` so if you return the value of `this` from the function then of course it'll return whatever the first argument was. There is no "side effect."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: "*suppose we only focus on cases where there is no `this` object for the function call*" - in those cases where the function is expected not to use the `this` argument, it doesn't matter whether you pass `undefined` or `null`. Neither is "safer". The latter is just more convenient to type.

Comment: try `console.log(obj.speak());` and see what the method "is supposed to" return. And the next method you should check out: [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). As in `let speak = obj.speak.bind(obj);` vs `let speak = obj.speak.bind({ foo: 42 });`